# Add directory symbolic link to Windows 10 Explorer quick access list

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

```
mklink /d link_folder target_folder
```

How to add link_folder to Windows 10 Explorer quick access list? Now if you drag it to quick access, the added folder point to target_folder .